# is Multiple setTimeout execution single threaded or mutli threaded in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, settimeout

Suppose I have 3 setTimeouts like below:

`console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString());`

`setTimeout(() => { console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString()); }, 3000);`

`setTimeout(() => { console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString()); }, 6000);`

`setTimeout(() => { console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString()); }, 9000);`

Since Node is single threaded, execution of each timeout should be one after the other. Hence the output should be as expected as below:

`9 am 0s (intial)`

`9 am 3s(+3s)`

`9 am 9s(+6s)`

`9 am 18s(+9s)`

But what I found was:

`9 am 0s (initial)`

`9 am 3s(+3s)`

`9 am 6s(+3s)`

`9 am 9s(+3s)`

So it was clear that all the timeouts have been started at the same time.. difference between each timeout was added to each which in this case was +3s,

Does this make nodejs multi-threaded in this case? I do know that not all parts of node run within the same thread and few do get executed outside the same thread.

Can someone provide me a better sense in this. Or maybe my approach is wrong.

Comment: JS is event-based. Other code can run while the timeout is pending (it's asynchronous)

Comment: The `setTimeout()` calls run one after the other in a very short period of time. The delay value in the first call has no effect (well, a minuscule effect) on the delay of the second call.

Comment: @blex I do know that functions that require node api do execute asynchronously, I was asking exection within node api ..

Comment: @ViswanadhDeepak not all of them. But functions that require a callback often do (except for things like `forEach`, `map`, etc.)

Comment: @Pointy yes that I did notice that setTimeout() calls are made at very minute differences of time...which If we consider scale to seconds then those calls are made at the same time...

Comment: @blex yes I am talking specifically the functions the use node api and have callbacks..will they get executed at the same time?

Comment: Yes, one right after the other. For example: `fs.readFile('a.txt', 'utf-8', () => console.log('a')); console.log('b'); fs.readFile('c.txt', 'utf-8', () => console.log('c'));` will always print `b` first, and then, depending on the time it takes to read the files, either `a c` or `c a`

Comment: @blex yes I do know asynchronous working..was wondering about sequential calls to node api that are non blocking in nature like mutliple i/o operations..timers..etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since Node is single threaded, execution of each timeout should be one after the other.

Node.js isn't single-threaded. But it does run a single JavaScript thread by default. You can run others via the [`worker_threads` module](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html). (Each worker gets its own JavaScript environment; they can communicate.)

> Hence the output should be as expected as below:

No, it shouldn't. Your code is starting three timers **one right after another**. All three calls to `setTimeout` are run immediately, starting their timer. Then the event loop continues, waiting for something to do, and about three seconds later it sees it's time for the first timer callback, so it runs that callback. Then the event loop continues. About three seconds after that (six in total), it sees that it's time for the second callback, and does that. The loop continues...and three seconds later, it does the third callback. This is all on a single thread.

There's more about the event loop in Node.js [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/).

Node's event loop is similar to the browser's. Here's your example in a browser, with some additional logging:

```js
const start = Date.now();

function elapsedPrefix() {
    return ("+" + (Date.now() - start)).padStart(4, " ");
}

function log(...msgs) {
    console.log(`${elapsedPrefix()}: ${msgs.join(" ")}`);
}

function now() {
    return new Date().toISOString().substring(11, 12);
}

function startTimeout(num, fn, ms) {
    log(`Start timer ${num} for ${ms}ms`);
    setTimeout(() => {
        log(`Timer ${num} firing`);
        fn();
    }, ms);
}

log(`Starting timers`);

startTimeout(1, () => { log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString()); }, 3000);
startTimeout(2, () => { log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString()); }, 6000);
startTimeout(3, () => { log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString()); }, 9000);

log(`Timers started`);
```

Comment: @Crowder, I was meant to say that it runs on single thread by default. Yes my question was will those timers launch at the same time? And if they did...will they be on the same thread? Just trying to distinguish which parts of node do mutli-threading if there are any

Comment: @ViswanadhDeepak - **All** of your JavaScript code will run on a single thread unless you use the `worker_threads` module. Node.js uses asynchronous I/O with an event loop on that thread, processing a queue of pending JavaScript jobs (like running a callback). Asynchronous I/O means I/O operations can be outstanding without holding things up. I *think* Node.js may have a couple of other utility threads it uses internally, but those aren't exposed to your code. Your code always runs in a single thread (unless you tell it not to). :-)

Comment: @Crowder Node uses v8 java script engine which is internally mostly single-threaded right? does that make nodejs single-threaded partially?

Comment: @ViswanadhDeepak - As far as I know, it's more of a design decision from the Node.js team, not least because JavaScript didn't have any concept of threading until recently and the only significant real-world implementations of it allowed only a single thread per what we now call a *realm* (basically a JavaScript global environment).